# Passing variables between batch file and .sql file for mssql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, batch-file

I am attempting to create a batch file in windows that will take a user's input, and pass that along to a sql file containing the following query, so that I can set a siteid, like in the following sql query:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver [sqlserver1]
select * from [sqlserver1].onesource.dbo.admsites where siteid = '123'
```

I want to then take the results of this query, particularly the admsiteid, and then use the results of the query, and insert that into the originatorid (using another .sql file:

```
Use Onesource
update OSCsettings set originatorid = 'whatever-the-admsiteid-is'
```

How would I go about passing along these variables?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2009/04/03/passing-parameters-to-sql-script-using-batch-files.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure about SQL injection vulnerabilities in this scenario.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is the syntax '[sqlserver1]' the correct way to reference a var arg?

Comment: Sam, nice link for the .bat file stuff.  You should have made it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

sqlcmd with the -v command line

-v var = "value"

You can specify multiple variables in the list.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx